# \left\langle \right\rangle command doesn't scale properly scale the brackets

Tags: brackets

The `\langle` and `\rangle` brackets don't scale properly according to the size of the contents within the brackets. Here is minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
        \norm{y}^2=\left\langle y,y\right\rangle&=\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i,\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j x_j\rangle=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \langle a_i x_i,a_j x_j\rangle
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Here is a screen shot. The `\langle` and `\rangle` brackets should be larger.

[image: A screen shot]

Comment: You are using the auto-scale `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle` for the `y,y` term (which doesn't need it). But around the `\sum`s you only have the non-scale `\langle...\rangle`. If you want auto-scale there, use `\left\langle...\righ\rangle` instead. Better would be to choose a good size manually: `\Bigl\langle \sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i,\ \sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j x_j\Bigr\rangle`

Comment: Make `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\inner[1]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1}` and use `\inner*{\sum...}`, though I'd use `\inner[\bigg]{\sum...}` and I'd even make `\inner` use two arguments

Comment: That said I can only recommend you copy the definition of `\innerp` from the `mathtools` documentation and use that: https://gist.github.com/moewew/8503d4cc27294a6473770ae453f0f3fb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's natural that you want that. So, type `\left\langle` and `\right\rangle` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already using `mathtools`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\innerp[2]{\langle}{\rangle}{
  #1, #2}
\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
      \norm{y}^2
      =\left\langle y,y\right\rangle
      &=\innerp[\bigg]{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i x_i}{\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_j x_j }
      =\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ \sum_{j=1}^{n} \innerp{ a_i x_i}{a_j x_j}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]